# Data Structure for privacy settings of profiles in the cloud

Tags: java, json, privacy

In a social app (similar to Facebook), a user's profile could look like this:

```
{"name": "Peter",
  "gender": "Male",
  "age": "22"}
```

Now, when people navigate to Peter's page, people would be able to see Peter's age, gender and name.

Let's say Peter is a very private person and he does not want anyone to know any of his personal information. I could structure the data to looks like this instead:

```
  {"name": "Peter",
  "alias":"GoofyDuck",
  "gender": "Male",
  "age": "22",
  "showGender": false,
  "showName":false,
  "showAge": false}
```

When other people navigate to his page, because of the boolean set in the json, the page could be prevent from displaying his details, however, if you have a lot of fields of personal details (for example, besides name, gender and age, Peter could put his address, phone number etc.), it could make the json unneccessarily long.

I was thinking maybe some type of mask on a binary string might be more appropriate:

```
  {"name": "Peter",
  "gender": "Male",
  "age": "22",
  "privacy":"110"}
```

In this case, the binary on the "privacy" field could say that only his age would be hidden as it is a 0.

I do think that the binary string is properly the most efficient way to store preferences on the cloud but I have not seen any examples of using a mask to mask out the meaning of the binary in java.

I could also parse out the binary string to get each value separately but think that won't be efficient. Is there a way I can mask out each value separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better design is to couple every property with its own privacy setrtings like this:

```
{ {"name": "Peter", "show": false},
  {"alias":"GoofyDuck", "show": false},
  {"gender": "Male", "show": false},
  {"age": "22", "show": false} }
```

This design carries several advantages:

1. more clear then having a mask where the settings is dependant on position in the mask
2. you can add new properties without worrying about affecting the privacy settings of existing ones
3. with this design, you can have more fine tune privacy settings, other than just boolean value:

   `{ {"name": "Peter", "show": "all"},
     {"alias":"GoofyDuck", "show": "all"},
     {"gender": "Male", "show": "friends"},
     {"age": "22", "show": "none"} }`
4. once you have a structure per property, you can enhance it with further metadata once it is required, for example,

   `{ {"name": "Peter", "show": "all", "decorate": "bold"},
     {"alias":"GoofyDuck", "show": "all"},
     {"gender": "Male", "show": "friends"},
     {"age": "22", "show": "none"} }`

Comment: Agreed with this design. Thanks! However,not sure how I would create it in mongodb... maybe i post another question on it.

Comment: Here's my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945922/creating-a-mongodb-entry-for-my-schema-using-the-java-driver

Answer (score 0):

you could just have a whitelist of visible attributes

`{public_attributes: {"name", "gender", "age"}`

note that you shouldn't use a blacklist because that may accidentally reveal data when you add new attributes

Comment: I want to be able to give the user the ability to make everything privacy if he so wishes. In my case, a whitelist doesn't exist.

Comment: well, that obviously would be an empty whitelist